# C# - Comparing UtcNow and UtcNow.Date does not work

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

The image below is self explanatory. How is it possible for the exact UTC time, and that same date at midnight to not compare correctly? Especially since these times are coming from the same object.

This seems like a bug in C# itself, but I know that can't be right. What am I missing here?

[image]

Extra details: If I increase `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` by 5 hours (in the 6 o clock hour), the comparison works correctly -- and works correctly for the rest of the day. Why is comparing between midnight and 6am broken?

What is *the* best way to compare universal time objects? (Timezones and locations don't matter. Only relative offsets matter.)

Comment: Date: *Gets a DateTime value that represents the **date component** of the current DateTimeOffset object.*  ([From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: @Plutonix thank you! How would you recommend making this comparison? (Best practices). The intent is to ensure one time (left) is within today -- or the object with that time was created today. So I'm comparing one point in time with midnight of the current day.

Comment: You're comparing a `DateTime` and a `DateTimeOffset`.  The comparison will implicitly convert the `DateTime` into a `DateTimeOffset`.  So, try casting `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Date` to back to a `DateTimeOffset`, and see what value it gives you.  I think you'll find that the comparison makes sense once you see the resulting value.  Furthermore, the `DateTime` object you have will have an unspecified kind.  The conversion back to a `DateTimeOffset` will therefore use the current timezone.

Comment: try: DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Ticks vs DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Date.Ticks

Comment: @Adam: "The intent is to ensure one time (left) is within today" "Today" from whose point of view (wich Timezone)? The same UTC time could end up being 3 different Dates at the same time, thanks to some of the insanity that is in Timezones (there are places with more then +/-12! Eveything else would be way to sensical)

Comment: @Christopher As mentioned at the end of my description: "What is the best way to compare universal time objects? (Timezones and locations don't matter. Only relative offsets matter.)"

Comment: This way may be better: DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Date.CompareTo(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.UtcDateTime) > 0

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks you two! Your two comments combined are what I was looking for: what's happening under the hood, and what the best way to do this is. If (both of you) want to add answers combining the two, I'd be happy to upvote them both.

Comment: @Sphinx Thanks you two! Your two comments combined are what I was looking for: what's happening under the hood, and what the best way to do this is. If (both of you) want to add answers combining the two, I'd be happy to upvote them both.

Comment: @Sphinx Thanks, I do like that second approach better. It seems less fragile and more readable -- the exact intent comes across better.

Comment: "Timezones and locations don't matter. Only relative offsets matter." - That's fine until you start talking about "the day" at which point time zones very much *do* matter. If you're talking about a "UTC day", then it's best to say that, IMO. (Btw, if the implicit conversions are causing a problem here, you may find my Noda Time library helps you - it makes this sort of code much simpler.)